# Redraw a d3 graph with new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, graph

I am new to d3 graphing and i am trying to draw a d3 node and edge graph with collected data and according to the name of the selected person the graph should change. 
[drawn graph for the initial time when first refresh happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIrg7.png)

[the graph drawn after selecting another persons data instead of the previous one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztt99.png)

```js
  /*
    Selecting a person from a option box default a person is selected. Therefore default grapgh id perfectly drawn but if somebody is selected later, the graph is not drawn but it stucks at a corner of the svg
    */

  $("#select-person").change(function(io) {


    drawGraph(top3, 3, dasIp);
    //top3 is a array of names of people
  });



  function drawGraph(topPeople, n, dasIp) {
    //radius --> retweet   color-->content
    //d3.select("#d3graph").select("svg").remove();
    var graph = {
      "nodes": [{
          "name": "Myriel",
          "group": 1
        }, {
          "name": "Napoleon",
          "group": 1
        }, {
          "name": "Mlle.Baptistine",
          "group": 1
        }, {
          "name": "Mme.Magloire",
          "group": 1
        }, {
          "name": "CountessdeLo",
          "group": 1
        }, {
          "name": "Geborand",
          "group": 1
        }, {
          "name": "Champtercier",
          "group": 1
        }, {
          "name": "Cravatte",
          "group": 1
        }, {
          "name": "Count",
          "group": 1
        }, {
          "name": "OldMan",
          "group": 1
        }, {
          "name": "Labarre",
          "group": 2
        },

        {
          "name": "Champmathieu",
          "group": 2
        }, {
          "name": "Brevet",
          "group": 2
        }, {
          "name": "Chenildieu",
          "group": 2
        },


        ..... {
          "name": "Brujon",
          "group": 4
        }, {
          "name": "Mme.Hucheloup",
          "group": 8
        }
      ],
      "links": [{
          "source": 1,
          "target": 0,
          "value": 1
        }, {
          "source": 2,
          "target": 0,
          "value": 8
        }, {
          "source": 3,
          "target": 0,
          "value": 10
        }, {
          "source": 3,
          "target": 2,
          "value": 6
        }, {
          "source": 4,
          "target": 0,
          "value": 1
        },

        .....

        {
          "source": 76,
          "target": 58,
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
    };


    var g = graphlibDot.read("digraph { A -> B;}");

    var graph = new Object();
    var map = new Object();
    var index = 0;

    var linkIndex = 0;
    var Nodes = [];
    var Edges = [];
    var dataN1 = [],
      dataN2 = [],
      dataN3 = [];
    var dataE1 = [],
      dataE2 = [],
      dataE3 = [];



    var width = $("#d3graph").width();
    var height = $("#d3graph").height();

    d3.select("#d3graph").selectAll("svg").remove();
    var svg = d3.select("#d3graph").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);


    `enter code here` // tool tip with the label
    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return d.name + "";
      })
    svg.call(tip);

    svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
      .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
      .enter().append("marker")
      .attr("id", function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
      .attr("refX", 25)
      .attr("refY", 0)
      .attr("markerWidth", 6)
      .attr("markerHeight", 6)
      .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
      .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
      .style("opacity", "0.6");

    var tableNodes = [],
      tableEdges = [];
    for (var t = 0; t < n; t++) {
      var tn = topPeople[t].name + "NODETWEETTABLE";
      tableNodes.push(tn);
      var te = topPeople[t].name + "EDGETWEETTABLE"
      tableEdges.push(te);

    }
    console.log(tableNodes);
    console.log(tableEdges);


    var tableColor = ["#3dff4f", "#0042b3", "#ff4533"];
    var nodeUrl1, nodeUrl2, nodeUrl3, edgeUrl1, edgeUrl2, edgeUrl3;

    function() {

      //Here data is successfully recieved from the ajax calls in the format of
      /*
                         Data Format NAMEEDGESTWEETTABLE
                        ================
                        source -STRING
                        target -STRING
                        value -INT

                        Data Format NAMENODESTWEETTABLE
                        ================
                        name  -STRING
                        group -INT
                        degree - INT decide size of the vertex


                         */

      loadNodeData(Nodes, dataN1, dataN2, dataN3);
      loadEdgesData(Edges, dataE1, dataE2, dataE3);
      renderNodesEdges(Nodes, Edges);

    }

    function loadNodeData(Nodes, dataN1, dataN2, dataN3) {
      for (var i = 0; i < dataN1.length; i++) {
        var d = dataN1[i].values;
        d.color = tableColor[0];
        Nodes.push(d);


      }
      for (var i = 0; i < dataN2.length; i++) {
        var d = dataN2[i].values;
        d.color = tableColor[1];
        Nodes.push(d);


      }
      for (var i = 0; i < dataN3.length; i++) {
        var d = dataN3[i].values;
        d.color = tableColor[2];
        Nodes.push(d);


      }


    }

    function loadEdgesData(Edges, dataE1, dataE2, dataE3) {
      for (var i = 0; i < dataE1.length; i++) {
        var d = dataE1[i].values;
        Edges.push(d);

      }
      for (var i = 0; i < dataE2.length; i++) {
        var d = dataE2[i].values;
        Edges.push(d);

      }
      for (var i = 0; i < dataE3.length; i++) { //
        var d = dataE3[i].values;
        Edges.push(d);

      }

    }

    function renderNodesEdges(dataset1, dataset2) {
      dataset1.forEach(function(d) {

        map[d.name] = index;
        d.degree = parseInt(d.degree)
        index++;
      });

      graph.nodes = dataset1;

      dataset2.forEach(function(d) {


        var s = map[d.source];
        var t = map[d.target];

        if (typeof s === "undefined" || typeof t === "undefined") {

          d.source = 1
          d.target = 2;



        } else {
          d.source = map[d.source];
          d.target = map[d.target];
          d.value = parseInt(d.value)
        }
      });

      graph.links = dataset2;
      console.log("both loaded 2");
      drapGraph(graph);



    }



    function drapGraph(graph) {
      svg.selectAll(".link").remove();
      svg.selectAll(".gnode").remove();
      var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-120)
        .linkDistance(20)
        .size([width, height])
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .links(graph.links)
        .start();

      var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([d3.min(graph.nodes, function(d) {
          return Math.log(d.group);
        }), d3.max(graph.nodes, function(d) {
          return Math.log(d.group);
        })])
        .range([0, 30]);

      var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke-width", 2)
        .style("stroke-length", function(d) {
          return (10000 / d.value);
        });
      var node = svg.selectAll(".gnode")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "gnode")
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
        .call(force.drag);

      var maxretweets = d3.max(graph.nodes, function(d) {
        return Math.log(d.group);
      });
      var minretweets = d3.min(graph.nodes, function(d) {
        return Math.log(d.group);
      });
      var maxContent = d3.max(graph.nodes, function(d) {
        return d.degree;
      });
      var minvalue = d3.min(graph.links, function(d) {
        return d.value;
      });

      var circle = node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) {
          return rScale(Math.log(d.group));
        })
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d.color;

        })
        .style("stroke", "#000000");

      var label = node.append("text")
        .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-size", "8")
        .style("stroke", "#404040")
        .text(function(d) {

          if (rScale(Math.log(d.group)) > 20) {
            return d.name;
          }
        });

      node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        });

      force.on("tick", function() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
          })
          .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
          })
          .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
          })
          .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
          });

        node.attr("cx", function(d) {
            return d.x;
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return d.y;
          });

        enter code here circle.attr("cx", function(d) {
            return d.x;
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return d.y;
          });

        label.attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.x;
          })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return d.y;
          });




      });




    }


  }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
  <div id="d3graph" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;" class="container">

  </div>

</div>
```

From the option box a default person is selected therefore on page load the graph of the default person is drawn. But when .onChange() of the option box called again the graph is not drawn but it stuck at the corner as shown in the image above. The data is perfectly coming from the the ajax calls.

Can somebody help me to figure out the problem in my code?

Comment: Can you add more code to your description? such as using jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: It would be easy to take a look if you can fiddle the code .

Comment: The both of the images looks the same..

Comment: I solved this problem by re-fetching data again and redrawing the graph again. I couldn't draw one graph on top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your line `d3.select("#d3graph").selectAll("svg").remove();` should work. That's what I do when the graph is too complicated to append data to.